# Could I use silicone caulk for installing bathtub drain

Tags: drain, bathtub

I am renovating a old bathroom with cast iron tub in it. I installed the drain flange using plumber putty and to make it water proof I had to tighten drain a lot. The drain elbow is 3/8 inch below the tub, so I need to tighten the drain flange more so that 3/8 inch gap is removed. This lead gasket to crack/split.

I would remove the drain flange and reinstall it. Could I silicone caulk instead of plumber putty?

Would that help seal the drain to tub better?

Any other tips where I can avoid leak and dont ave to tighten the drain so much to remove the 3/8 inch gap?

[image]

Comment: Are the drain flange and elbow creating a solid connection? You may need a bigger gasket or spacers if there's still too much room between the bottom of the tub and the drain elbow. Caulk probably isn't the answer for plumbing components designed to install without it, you'll be better off with standard installation.

Comment: @FredricShope  the tub bottom and elbow has 3/8  or 1/2 inch gap even after putting gasket there. To remove this gap, I need to tighten the flange more than usual.

Comment: @FredricShope would something like this thick gasket work?  https://www.amazon.com/Danco-Inc-88349-Gasket-Rubber/dp/B000VZM3N6/ref=pd_bxgy_1/145-8724957-9148130?pd_rd_w=ZBWPp&pf_rd_p=c64372fa-c41c-422e-990d-9e034f73989b&pf_rd_r=WTEPYV8FC65B7V07XEYV&pd_rd_r=458a24e5-0743-4628-a43e-db063bf3e02d&pd_rd_wg=CmeMi&pd_rd_i=B000VZM3N6&psc=1

Comment: If the overflow assembly is accessible, you should be able to raise the waste tee a little bit by loosening the slip joint nuts for the overflow tube and tailpiece. This will bring the drain elbow closer to flush with the bottom of the tub. When it's correctly positioned, re-tighten the slip joint nuts.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings Thank you for the advice. I thought that but it is hard to reach to the slip joint nut. Also the slip joint nut seems to be joined by lead.

Comment: You should not have had to tighten it that much.  It doesn't have to hold _pressurized_ water.  Perhaps there is a leak somewhere else.